# trying to understand how checksum is calculated

Tags: algorithm, pyserial, checksum

I am looking at [this page](https://github.com/tagyoureit/nodejs-poolController/wiki/Chlorinator) and I am not sure how the author is calculating the checksum.  I would contact the author directly, but don't have his email address (its not listed in github).

This is a simple example of a packet with no variables.  The author calculates the checksum to be 120 (I assume this is hex as all his other values are in hex).  The sum of all the bytes is 0xBA hex or 186 base(10).  His notes say "Checksum Low Bit, This bit is checksum of 1-5 bits (MOD 256, if necessary)" but I am not getting what he is saying and I can't figure out how to get to his answer.

```
Get Version / Return Name
Byte    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
Request 16  2   80  20  2   120 16  3
Byte    Sample hex       Definition
         hex (B10)
====    ==== =====       =============================
1       0x16  (22)       Preamble 1
2       0x02   (2)       Preamble 2
3       0x80 (128)       Destination = Chlorinator
4       0x20  (32)       Command = Get Name
5       0x02   (2)       Not sure. Intellitouch uses 2. Aquarite uses 0. Any of them seem to work.
6       120              Checksum Low Bit, This bit is checksum of 1-5 bits (MOD 256, if necessary)
7       0x16  (22)       Post-amble 1
8       0x3    (3)       Post-amble 2
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: I had never heard from this spec, so my guess is as good as yours. But Googling leads me to believe that the checksum is simply the sum of the values up to that point (modulo 256 if it overflows, because it's a single byte only). So it seems to me that the author is mixing up decimal and hexidecimal numbers in that example and computes 16+2+80+20+2=120 as if it were decimal. It would seem to me that the correct checksum is AA (186).

Comment: I could not find where it is indicated that the values `1, 2, 128, ...` are expressed in hexa. I suppose that everything is expressed in digital, which solved your issue. In all the examples displayed on the page, I could not find any pure hexa digit: `A B C ... F`.

Comment: OMG!  So simple.  I guess I was more tired that I thought last night.  Thanks guys, that did it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the commentors were 100% correct: the numbers were express in decimal, not hex as I assumed.